# Java swing menu control not align

Tags: java, swing, alignment, jmenu

I created a swing application which looks fine on 2 laptops with JDK8 but on 3rd laptop, all menu controls going little down. I am attaching image.
I created maven structure where below java file and pom is present.  Only these two files. Run either using maven or main method.

[image: Correct and Problem image]

**Java Code**

```
package com.sv.test;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Test extends JFrame {
    public Test() {
        JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu m = new JMenu("*");
        mb.add(m);

        JToolBar tb = new JToolBar();
        tb.setFloatable(false);
        tb.setRollover(false);
        tb.add(new JTextField(15));
        tb.add(new JTextField(15));
        tb.add(mb);
        JButton exit = new JButton("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(e -> System.exit(0));
        tb.add(exit);
        tb.setBackground(Color.orange);

        getContentPane().add(tb);

        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.sv</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Command to compile**

```
mvn install
```

**Command to run**

```
mvn exec:java -D"exec.mainClass"="com.sv.test.Test"
```

Comment: How to reproduce the problem? Is it resolution-dependent?  LAF dependent? OS?

Comment: Laptop has JDK1.8.0_251 on which layout is going off but I am NOT able to reproduce on other laptop.

Comment: The JMenuBar is added to the JFrame, not the JToolBar.  Move the setDefaultCloseOperation method call above the pack method call.

Comment: No Gilbert, check code - tb.add (mb).  Also, I tried by moving pack method but result remain same.

Comment: When @GilbertLeBlanc wrote *"The JMenuBar is added to the JFrame"* he meant the menubar *should* be added to the frame. Use [`JFrame.setJMenuBar(JMenuBar)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setJMenuBar(javax.swing.JMenuBar)) to do that.

Comment: Hi Andrew - I tested it but by adding menu bar to frame shifts menu to the top bar.  My requirement is to put menu in toolbar.

Comment: If you put components in places they're not designed to go, expect the unexpected. 

Comment: But Pal - how this is working in other laptop ? Could this be java minor version diff ?  Check first image

Comment: *"how this is working in other laptop ?"* Do you understand what 'unexpected' means and implies? *"But Pal"* NVM - I thought you might be talking to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237867/discussion-between-shailu-and-andrew-thompson).

Comment: No. For chats I use FB. I also hate FB and rarely open it.

Comment: No problem - Yeah I referred you as Pal.  Today I checked in 3rd laptop where it is working fine.  So 2 are showing UI correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default layout to JToolbar is BoxLayout.  In case of JMenu as one of item in JToolbar this goes off due to BoxLayout.
You need to manually set layout and manage margins which will solve your problem.
I add below line to your code and it worked but put some margins between buttons.

```
tb.setLayout (new FlowLayout());
```

You can read more about JToolbar [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html)

Comment: Wow !! Still I am not sure why its working on other two laptops.  Only difference is they have JDK 11 but via maven I am using 8 version.  You suggestion is working fine on all machines and yes I need to correct the margins.  Thanks.